# As AD Carry, is it better to stay alive and attack harder targets than to kill enemy carries?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the Solo Queue games i play i sometimes get raged at because i didn't attack the opponents AD/AP carry but rather stayed back and attacked targets that were safer for me, like the bruisers or even the tank.

I then in response went and tried to attack the target they wanted me to attack but usually ended up dead after getting maybe 2-3 shots off and then getting raged at because i didn't manage to kill the target.

Should i let people continue to rage at me and survive or play more risky in teamfights and hope my team does something to protect me?

EDIT:
I usually play Graves, Corki or Caitlyn.

Comment: What carry do you usually play? There are slightly different styles for each (think Twitch stealth, shorter range compared to Tristana longest range, gap closer or Ashe: long range + good CC)

Comment: @gbn I updated the question.

Comment: There's an ignore button for a reason; play how you like!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always be targeting the immediate threat. If the bruiser is the one dealing out all of the damage then attack them. You should never be targeting the tank. That's what they want you to do. Killing the tank may give you an advantage, but all that time spent killing him could have been spent killing everyone but him.

However, don't play risky. I hate to say it, but don't ever especially in solo que rely on the tank or the support to keep you alive. Not only is it a very tough task since you can be killed so easily, but that also assumes that the tank/support knows what they are doing (which is rare) Staying alive especially late game as the carry is very essential, being that you are the primary damage dealer and your death could mean a hard push on your team or even an ace. Also, you will most likely be losing some stacks, bloodthirster or something of that nature.

If your team is mad at you for not targeting the right people, make sure you know who the threat is going into a teamfight and know where they position themselves. If you have to seperate from the team to get a good attack advantage don't be afraid to. The brush is a very good friend of the squishy AD carry.

Comment: Usually the biggest threat to my team are the opponents carries (at least according to my teammates) that are most of the time quite far back so unless i flank their whole team and attack from his back i won't get in his range without being in range of everyone else. If i understand your answer correctly, you are saying i should still attack him unless someone else got fed so much that he does more damage?

Comment: If you can get free hits (w/o burning much mana/CDs) on the tank when you're sizing up for a team fight, I don't see much harm in that (or simply isolate and kill them if they're out of position) Once everything is going on, yeah, totally ignore them.

Comment: @dbmerlin Your purpose is to eliminate their damage dealers first, if their AD carry is horrible (which is compeltley possible) then go after whoever is dealing their primary damage. But, more importantly don't put yourself in a situation where you're going to get killed easily. Play the map, know your enemy and locations to strike from to get an advantage. Also yes, Nick I agree damaging the tank doesn't hurt, but overall in a teamfight your role as an AD carry is to lessen their damage output. Even if it doesn't result in a kill, zoning a powerful support/carry out of a teamfight is clutch.

Comment: Splitting off as an AD carry is a really bad idea that will turn a 5v5 into a 4v5 quick. :/

Comment: @Snuffleupagus If you built well and have good map awareness you can afford to take a section of brush near but not with your team.

Comment: Wouldnt it be the goal of the Assassins like Ahri or Akali ( or if there are none some bruisers like Riven) to focus the enemy carry? Usually the enemy carry stays behind the fighting line , so if you try to run to him (with urself being the ad-carry) you would expose yourself to all the other enemies. I think you should focus the biggest thread which is part of the "real fight" (I mean this mob where all the melees are). Of course, if you have an easy opportunity to focus enemy ap/ad carry, go for it. But don't waste to much time walking around.

Answer (score 1):

As an AD carry your damage potential is only limited by your survivability, so your positioning in team fights is paramount. In team fights you should always prioritize the enemy carries, but do not sacrifice your positioning to attack these high-value targets.